# Number Theory : Show that $\sigma(n)$ $=$ $2n$ for $n$ $=$ $(2^{m-1})$ $(2^{m} -1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

I was working through some basic Number Theory Problems when I came across :

> Given an integer $m$ $≥ 2$ such that $(2^{m} -1)$ is a prime, and $n$ $=$ $(2^{m-1})$$(2^{m} -1)$, then show that $\sigma(n)$ $=$ $2n$ where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of the divisors of an integer $x$

I am not able to make progress ,can someone help me out ; even a hint will suffice

Comment: For a hint, note that $\sigma$ is multiplicative, so $\sigma(n)=\sigma(2^{m-1})\sigma(2^m-1)$, Both of these are easy to compute.

Comment: Taking $m=2$ gives $n=6$, and $6$ is indeed a perfect number, the smallest one.  The OR is (was) wrong,

Comment: Oh , @AndréNicolas , sorry - I was calculating something else :P

Comment: That is actually the [Euler-Euclid Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem) for even perfect numbers $\geq 6$. We know that for all even perfect numbers $n$, $\sigma(n)=2n$. Hence follows your answer. You can see the proofs there.

Comment: Hi , @PrasunBiswas , thanks a ton :) If you can give that as an answer , then I will be able to accept it :)

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas for the hint :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $2^{m-1}$, the only numbers that divide it are of form $2^k$ over $0 \leq k \leq m-1$, so $\sigma(2^{m-1}) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} 2^k = 2^m-1$ via geometric series.

For prime $2^m-1$ (also known as a Mersenne prime), the only divisors it has are $1$ and itself, so $\sigma(2^m-1) = 2^m$ in this case.

Since $\sigma$ is multiplicative, we have $\sigma(ab) = \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$ where $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Therefore $\sigma((2^{m-1})(2^m-1)) = \sigma(2^{m-1})\sigma(2^m-1) = (2^m-1)(2^m) = 2n$.

Comment: but what if m is not a prime number ?